# Difference between convergence in measure and almost everywhere convergence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

We say$$f_n  \rightarrow f$$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$ $iff$ there exist N in sigma algebra $F$ such that $\mu$(N) = $0$ and $$f_n(\omega)\rightarrow f(\omega)$$ for all $\omega$ in $N^c$

and 
$$f_n \rightarrow f$$ converges in measure $iff$ for all $\epsilon$ > $0$   $\mu${ $\omega$ in $\Omega$ : |$f_n(\omega)$ - $f(\omega)$| > $\epsilon$ } = $0$.

Now, can we say these:

1)In almost everywhere convergence, we have infinitely many $f_n$ tend to $f$ except finitely many or countably many $f_n$,

2)In convergence in measure, we have for infinitely $n$,   $f_n$s tend to $f$ except for finitely $f_n$

The point that I couldn't understand is, what is the difference between convergence in measure and almost everywhere convergence?

Comment: in your definition of convergence in measure the limit is missing

Comment: Your two questions are completely unclear. Concerning the difference between the two notions : if the measure is finite, then a.s. convergence implies convergence in measure; but not conversely.

Comment: I edited the questions.

Comment: I still do not see at all what your questions mean.